# Set hibernate.ddl-auto in springboot programmatically

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I use springboot in a non web application and data jpa. I use the default configuration except for datasource:

```
private static final String dataSourceUrl = "jdbc:h2:./Database;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE";
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().url(dataSourceUrl).username("user").password("pwd").build();
}
```

How can I set the spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto property also programmatically?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-one-configuration/

Comment: It helped, thanks :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Adding the following bean seems to do the job (thanks to Jens' comment):

```
  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource);
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "packages.to.scan" });

    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    em.setJpaProperties(properties);

    return em;
  }
```