# Spring Boot forbid property value

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Is there a way to forbid a given property value, passed in the Spring configuration(e.g. application.proeprties).

For example if we want to prevent unexpected database schema migration when using hibernate. 
Let's say that we want to use only the value `validate` of the property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto`. If the value is not `validate` throw an exception or override it to `validate`.

Is that possible? Maybe there is some "hook" or pre-processor where one can check the properties before the application is started.

Comment: I guess, one can do this programmatically rather with application.properties values. May be there is a bean for custom configuration.

Comment: If this help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/34223842/2950010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `EnvironmentPostProcessor` to look at the environment and do whatever you like. [This section of the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-customize-the-environment-or-application-context) explains how you can do this.

> It is also possible to customize the Environment before the application context is refreshed using EnvironmentPostProcessor. Each implementation should be registered in META-INF/spring.factories:
>
> `org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=com.example.YourEnvironmentPostProcessor`